# How to have a variable changing XPATH - Selenium , python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I've tried finding a xpath containing certain text in my case the word 'follow' but it appears like it cannot find the elements.
In order to get around this I click the 'follow' button by xpath - however these are dynamic and change every line.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[26]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[27]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[28]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[29]/div[3]/a/span[2]/span").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[30]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[31]/div[3]/a/span[2]/span").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[32]/div[3]/a/span[2]/span").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[33]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[34]/div[3]/a/span[2]/span").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[35]/div[3]/a/span[2]").click()
```

But this is time consuming to do line by line - so I was thinking what if I had a variable of `"//div['X+1']/div[3]/a/span[2]"` - how would I type this.
Also would I be able to just place into the code like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("variable").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'theText')]]
```

will find objects with the textnode 'theText'

```
//*[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@attribute), ' '), ' value ')]
```

will find nodes where the attribute 'attribute' has the value 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
String xpathPrefix = "//div[";
String xpathSuffix = "]/div[3]/a/span[2]";

for (int i =26; i < 32; i++) {
    String fullXpath = xpathPrefix + String.valueOf(i)+ xpathSuffix ;
    driver.find_element_by_xpath.click(fullXpath);
}
```